AWS Elastic Beanstalk takes ages to update environment
All of a sudden and without changing anything, AWS EB, started taking ages to update the environment after a new code deployment.
I am getting this message:
Elastic Beanstalk is updating your environment. To cancel this operation select Abort Current Operation from the Actions dropdown.
There is nothing I can do apart from aborting the operation, deleting the environment and creating a new one every time I want a new deployment.
I am using nodejs.
How can I troubleshoot?
Update In the logs I see the following
"Environment health has transitioned from Info to Warning. Application update failed 16 seconds ago and took 15 minutes. None of the instances are sending data."
However, EC2 instance is running.
